# What is this strange Weller soldering iron tip used for?

Tags: soldering

This is a Weller ET DS (4ETDS-1) soldering tip for the Weller WE 1010 soldering station. What's it for (because it looks daft to me)?

[image: tip]

Comment: It might be used for heat staking, especially because it doesn't look like the tip has been tinned at all, but even then the tip doesn't look burned. Heat staking tips aren't tinned so use a plating that does not oxidize easily but also does not wet, like chrome.

Comment: Looking into the [Weller catalog](https://media-weller.de/weller/data/ebooks/epaper-Weller_Catalogue_2016-17_EN/index.html#104) it doesn't appear that the picture you show matches the description of the part number you provided. Are you sure of the number?

Comment: Through-hole solder removal in conjunction with a solder sucker?

Comment: @jonk I assumed (I'm an ass) that it was correct as in https://www.amazon.co.uk/Weller-4ETAA-1-Soldering-Chisel-Thickness/dp/B01M0PYH9R/ref=pd_di_sccai_2/260-3672364-9110667.

Comment: @jonk See https://www.amazon.co.uk/Weller-4ETAA-1-Soldering-Chisel-Thickness/dp/B071PF7RZ5/ref=pd_di_sccai_2/260-3672364-9110667?th=1. Very similar...

Answer (score 10):

I would say it's for heat-staking.

Some plastic assemblies are designed with pins that will go through a hole in a PCB/Chassis. Whilst clamped in place, the back-end of the pin is melted down so that it's larger than he hole and will hold the panel in place, once cooled.

Edit: Actually as commented below, It's almost certainly for fitting heat-set threaded inserts.

Comment: similarly, maybe for pushing heat-set threaded inserts into plastic

Comment: @user371366 - I think you're right, that's most likely it.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that is that it would primarily be used for desoldering. It would be flat when new (not sure why it’s pictured with solder on the end).

Like this:
[image: flat]

The shape gives it excellent heat transfer and the flat end helps to spread the heat across the wick.

Comment: Ah, ah, ah! That 'nipple' is solder? I thought that it was part of the tip as it's so symmetrical...

Comment: doesn't look like solder to me, either. But Blair's point stands. Maybe it's a special desoldering tip for solder-filled holes!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yeah maybe. I wondered that too. The photo I posted was actually for the 4ETDS-1 (the part number in the OP). But I can’t say if it was an exact representation or more of a stock photo.